# jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu with ActionBarSherlock show the slidingmenu without covering the whole screen?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu with ActionBarSherlock. When I slide to right, the slidingmenu shows perfectly (shows only at a certain width). But when I tap on a button(SLIDEMENU) to show the slidingmenu (using toggle()), it shows the whole menu (covers the whole screen). How to show the slidingmenu without covering the whole screen? Here is my activity and menu xml..

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity{

private static final int SLIDEMENU = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);        
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);        
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    menu.setBehindWidth((displaymetrics.widthPixels)/2);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,SLIDEMENU,0,"Menu")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.btnmenu)
    .setShowAsAction(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == SLIDEMENU) {
        toggle();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**sliding_menu.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/menuWidth"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/test1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menuWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
    android:text="@string/test1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menuWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
    android:text="@string/test2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test3"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/menuWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
    android:text="@string/test3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `behindWidth`

```
    menu.setBehindWidth(your-value-here);
```

Comment: Maybe, you would like to set static value rather than `(displaymetrics.widthPixels)/2`

Comment: (displaymetrics.widthPixels)/2 this part is working on my code. The problem is when I tap on the button on actionbar that triggers toggle(), it shows the menu covering the whole screen.

Comment: Yes. I know it's working. I am saying that you might want to try with some static value rather than `(displaymetrics.widthPixels)/2` once.

Answer (score 0):

Searching I found the following:

```
  SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
  sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenuWidth);
  sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenuOffset);
  sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
  sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

  <dimen name="slidingmenuWidth">15dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="slidingmenuOffset">60dp</dimen>
```